# Is it possible to disable jumping to the end of a list?

Tags: python

In the program I am writing, it would be very convenient to disable the ability to jump to the end of a list by using negative numbers. What I mean is that I would want this:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
number = list[-1]
print(number)
```

NOT to output 4, but to for example give me an IndexError like it would if I tried to access the 5th entry in the list.

New to programming so not sure if something like this could be done, but it would save me a lot of code. Of course I could work around it, but it would be neat if this option existed!

Comment: Why would that be *convenient* exactly? Even if you did the necessary to prevent what's a fundamental and understood part of Python indexing - it's going to completely confuse things for any other poor soul that has to work with your code (including yourself in future no doubt). It might depending how you work around it - break pretty much most of the standard library and any 3rd party modules you'd expect to be able to use...

Comment: This can be done, but if you are new to programming I wouldn't recommend it. It is relatively complex and you would be better off finding an alternative solution as opposed to trying to alter core Python

Comment: you would be better inserting a test to ensure that the index value passed never fell below 0, instead changing negative index values to 0 before using them in a list.

Comment: So you want to cancel negative indexing (e.g. `list[-1], list[-2]`)?

Comment: @direprobs Yes, that was my idea. But since it seems like it was not a good idea, I will find another method. ;)

Comment: Like what @PaulCollingwood said, you can insert a test like: `if(index >= 0):...`. Otherwise, you can define a proxy class that delegates its functionality to `list` built-in class and alter and customize the indexing to not accept negative integers, but this is advanced and might be frowned-upon.

Comment: Basically you can subclass the list and overload all the index related methods: `__getitem__`, `__ setitem__`... But since it is a native type, it is an advanced topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if index<0:
    value = l[0]
else:
    value = l[index]
```

Also **list** is a keyword in python, so don't use it like you have in your example.

Comment: Thanks, the best idea seemed to not do what I wanted to do, so I'll mark this as the answer as it is a better solution.

Comment: being able to use [-1] for the last item *will* come in handy at some point ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what are you trying to accomplish by doing that but you may attempt to override `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` like so:

```
class NewList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, int) and key < 0:
            raise IndexError("Cannot index to values lower than 0.")
        return super().__getitem__(key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(key, int) and key < 0:
            raise IndexError("Cannot index to values lower than 0.")
        return super().__setitem__(key, value)

list = NewList
```

Keep in mind doing so is not a really good idea and might cause internal problems so I wouldn't suggest it.

Answer (score 0):

Negative indexing `lst[-1]` is basicly the same as `lst[len(lst)-1]`, which is positive indexing. So what you want to do doesn't really make sense, as items at those places will still be accessible.

But you can do it anyway like this:

```
class CustomList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, slice):
            if key.start < 0 or key.stop < 0:
                raise TypeError("Negative indexes are not allowed")
            else:
                super(self.__class__, self).__getitem__(key)
        elif isinstance(key, int):
            if key < 0:
                raise TypeError("Negative indexes are not allowed")
            else:
                super(self.__class__, self).__getitem__(key)
        else:
            raise TypeError("Index must be a slice object or an integer")

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, slice):
            if key.start < 0 or key.stop < 0:
                raise TypeError("Negative indexes are not allowed")
            else:
                super(self.__class__, self).__delitem__(key)
        elif isinstance(key, int):
            if key < 0:
                raise TypeError("Negative indexes are not allowed")
            else:
                super(self.__class__, self).__delitem__(key)
        else:
            raise TypeError("Index must be a slice object or an integer")

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(key, slice):
            if key.start < 0 or key.stop < 0:
                raise TypeError("Negative indexes are not allowed")
            else:
                super(self.__class__, self).__setitem__(key, value)
        elif isinstance(key, int):
            if key < 0:
                raise TypeError("Negative indexes are not allowed")
            else:
                super(self.__class__, self).__setitem__(key, value)
        else:
            raise TypeError("Index must be a slice object or an integer")

alist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(alist[-1])
print(alist[-3:-1])
blist = CustomList([1, 2, 3, 4])
print(blist[1])
print(blist[1:3])
blist[1] = 10
print(blist)
blist[1:3] = [20, 30]
print(blist)
try:
    print(blist[-1])
except TypeError as ex:
    print(ex)
try:
    print(blist[-3:-1])
except TypeError as ex:
    print(ex)
try:
    blist[-1] = 100
except TypeError as ex:
    print(ex)
    print(blist)
try:
    blist[-3:-1] = [200, 300]
except TypeError as ex:
    print(ex)
    print(blist)
try:
    del blist[-1]
except TypeError as ex:
    print(ex)
    print(blist)    
del blist[len(blist)-1]
print(blist)
```

This will give the following output:

```
4
[2, 3]
None
None
[1, 10, 3, 4]
[1, 20, 30, 4]
Negative indexes are not allowed
Negative indexes are not allowed
Negative indexes are not allowed
[1, 20, 30, 4]
Negative indexes are not allowed
[1, 20, 30, 4]
Negative indexes are not allowed
[1, 20, 30, 4]
[1, 20, 30]
```